# Twitter Bootstrap 4 navbar-toggleable-*

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Given the code below is the supposed behavior that the button is hidden at `lg` and `xl`; while the collapsed content is only toggeable at `md` or is it toggeable from `md` downto `xs`?  Can someone help explain this?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-lg-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2">
    &#9776;
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-md" id="exCollapsingNavbar2">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Responsive navbar</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Alpha software. It’s liable to be broken.

Answer (score 2):

It becomes toggleable at medium and is from medium down.

The `navbar-toggleable-*` means that *from * down it is able to be toggled*.

I have been working with this today, and that is the behavior that I have seen and is described in bootstrap docs

Answer (score 1):

Used **navbar-expand-** This means it always in collapsed mode